# popup message in c# for single button with two operations

Tags: c#, javascript, html, mysql, asp.net

I am working on asp.net using c#. For my project am using single button with two operations one for insertion and another one for deletion using "Selected Index". Two buttons are working for save data and to delete, but while written code to pop-up message for delete confirmation like alert(yes/no) its taking popup message for both insertion and deletion. Please suggest code to me either in c# or in java script. Help me.
   Thanks in advance

This code am using,

```
        protected void SaveCountry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Country.Text != "")       {
         if (SaveCountry.Text == "Save")       {
            bal_obj.CO_NAME = Country.Text;
            if (bal_obj.Add_country(bal_obj))  //This for Save                {
                Country.Text = "";                }             }         }

              else            {                                                                  

            bal_obj.CO_ID = int.Parse(SelectCountryForUpdate.SelectedValue.ToString());
            bal_obj.CO_NAME = Country.Text;
            if (bal_obj.Dropcountry(bal_obj))    //This for Delete  {
                SelectCountryForUpdate.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Country.Text = "";    }   }  }
```

I need to show confirmation message for delete.

Comment: How are you performing your logic?  Show some code to demonstrate the problem.  It sounds like a very strange UX to have the same button do different things like that.  If you're showing the pop-up when the button is clicked then, well, expect to see a pop-up when the button is clicked.  Otherwise, if you have some condition you want to check before showing it, check that condition before showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom attribute to the button, like:

```
<asp:button  myActionType="action1" onClientClick="popup(this);">
```

and in the popup function use Javascript to get the value of myActionType

EDIT:

You can retrieve the custom attribute in the code behind as well.